# как воспроизвести звук с микрофона после Fast Furier Transform (Python)

Tags: python

В Python необходимо в звуке от микрофона отфильтровать часть низких частот и воспроизвести отфильтрованный звук. Безусловно всё делаю неправильно. Перед проверкой кода, настоятельно рекомендую выкрутить громкость звука на минимум.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
import numexpr as ne
import time

CHUNK = 1024
RATE = 10000
WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 1

data_end = np.zeros(CHUNK//2)  
data2 = np.zeros(CHUNK//4) 

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK//4)

a = input("Сделайте громкость на минимум, т.к. будет проигрываться громкий шум. Для продолжение нажмите на кнопку Enter ") 

while True:
    data1 =[]
    data1.append(stream.read(CHUNK//2))
    data1[0] = np.fromstring(data1[0], np.int16)

    # Чтобы длина массива данных не уменьшилась в два раза (с 1024 до 512), 
    # массив с данными соединяю с пустым массивом такой же длины:
    data1[0] = np.concatenate((data1[0], data_end), axis=None)

    sound = []
    sound = list(data1[0])
    sound = np.asarray(sound, dtype='float64')
    sound = sound[0:CHUNK]
    
    # Преобразование Фурье:
    sound_fft = np.fft.fft(sound)
    sound_fft = sound_fft.real
    sound_fft = abs(sound_fft[0:CHUNK//2])
    
    # Фильтр низких частот
    sound_fft[0:10] = 0
        
    # Обратное преобразование Фурье
    sound_ifft = np.fft.ifft(sound_fft)
    
    # Веществ.
    sound_ifft = sound_ifft.real
    
    # Восстановление сигнала, но с длиной в 4 раза меньше первоначальной (не 1024, а 256)
    data2 = sound_ifft[0:CHUNK//4]
    data2[0] = 0
```

Comment: Что означает "не получается"?

Comment: @Эникейщик Давно не могу разобраться как выполнить обратное преобазование Фурье и перевести в битовые данные.

Comment: А вообще мне кажется вы тучу каких-то не очень понятных манипуляций делаете с `data1` и `sound`, проверьте, что вы там данные не портите по дороге случайно.

Comment: Распишите пожалуйста в чем конкретно проблема. Представьте, что вы отвечаете на свой вопрос и видите условие "_необходимо в звуке от микрофона отфильтровать часть низких частот и воспроизвести отфильтрованный звук. Безусловно всё делаю неправильно_" и все.

Answer (score 3):

Такие вещи ищутся элементарно. Просто гуглите "numpy fast fourier transform", находите документацию на используемую вами функцию [np.fft.fft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html). В документации после описания функции всегда идёт раздел **See also** он часто бывает очень полезным. И что мы там видим буквально на второй же строчке:

> `ifft` The inverse of fft.

Это и есть обратное преобразование Фурье. Попробуйте использовать эту функцию [np.fft.ifft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html).

Comment: Исправил текст, т.к. вопрос поставил некорректно. Цель - воспроизвести звук, а не выполнить обратное преобразование Фурье.

Comment: @DontMansion Не делайте так в будущем, это запрещено правилами, потому что данные вам ответы перестают соответствовать вопросу. Да и название вопроса у вас осталось прежним при этом, а спрашиваете в теле вопроса вы другое уже. В таких случаях положено задавать новый вопрос.